# Sharepoint 2010 Navigation Audience target audience did not work

Tags: audience-targeting

I am try to limit a menu item to certain users. 
To get there I click on "Site Actions : Site Settings"
Under "Look and Feel" I click "Navigation"
Under "Navigation Editing and Sorting" I select the link that I want to limit who can see it.
I edit the link and add the group I want to target but it doesnt work.
Everone is still able to see the link.

Am I missing a step?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I didnt know how to do that. I thought clicking the "was this feedback helpful" accepted it. but I see the check mark in the circle now. Thanks for the info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your User Profile Service Application is running, Audience Targeting doesn't work if User Profile Service Application is not running!